# Два восклицательных знака

Tags: пунктуация

Задался вопросом, можно ли ставить два восклицательных знака, показывая более яркие эмоции, чем при одном, но из скромности не доходя до трёх (чтобы собеседник не подумал, что я в полнейшем восторге, и не нашёл в этом фальши).

Пошукал в Интернете и нашёл [вот что](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85):

> ***Вопрос № 294611***
>
> Здравствуйте! Прошу по возможности указать, есть ли правило русского языка, в котором прописано, что в конце предложения не ставятся два восклицательных (вопросительных) знака, а также две точки (..)? Это я к чему: на космодроме "Восточный" на огромных баннерах, щитах и плакатах размещена фраза "Подними голову!!" Есть ли ошибка в написании?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Употребление двух восклицательных знаков правилами пунктуации не предусмотрено. В приведенной Вами фразе достаточно одного знака.
>
> Однако правила не запрещают использовать в целях создания художественной выразительности различные необычные комбинации знаков. Вот пример подобного пунктуационного творчества: *Там они расстались, под соснами, на песчаной тропе. Игорь, как мог, остановил мгновение: Александр Александрович!!. чтобы в лицо... но это был уже кто-то совсем другой, хоть и тоже в белой рубашке, но с ракеткой под мышкой: стоял поближе к кустам и озирался направо и налево... (А. Битов).*

Грамота вроде всё разъяснила, но всё же хочется узнать: может быть, будут мнения, отличные от этого, или какие-то дополнения к нему.

Comment: Ну как тут могут быть мнения авторитетнее, чем мнение Грамоты? Что, собственно, не устраивает в ответе Грамоты?

Comment: Пример, конечно, забавный — «!!.» и далее, после точки, со сторочной. Творчество не задушишь: правила не запрещают. Филькина всё разъяснила.

Comment: И правда! Даже не посмотрел: "!!." :)))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - т.н. *мнение "Грамоты"* давно никаким особым авторитетом не пользуется. На самом деле это мнение "Справочного бюро", где за копейки подрабатывают стуленты первых курсов. Зайдите на сайт "Грамоты" - и попытайтесь уточнить фйормулировку какого-нибудь ответа (а там ояпов столько, что только ленивый не найдет). Вас, скорее всего, даже не допупстят к разговору, хотя там и место специальное под него выделенно. http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewforum.php?f=15

Comment: То же самое происходит на интсанрамме - только в одни ворота. Никаких обсуждений. Последнее время "Нрамота" вообще перестала заниматься проблемами собственно языка - и превратилась исключительно в самопиарющаюся организацию по выбиванию грантов.

Comment: Это в отношении авторитетности "Грамоты" вообще. Что касается ответа, то он сам по себе вполне обоснован и сомнений не вызывает. Если мне память не изменяет, дан он был еще в древние времена, когда "Грамота" более следила за базаром. Или как вариант - скопипасчен с более древнего ответа. Ибо я не могу точно вспомнить, когда он был дан, а разбираться неохота... Но не менее пяти лет назад я что-то подобное там видел..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В классической художественной литературе повторение восклицательных знаков (и другие "комбинации") встречается довольно часто.

*Багровость Филипп Филипповича приняла несколько сероватый оттенок.

— В спальне принимать пищу, – заговорил он придушенным голосом, — в смотровой — читать, в приемной — одеваться, оперировать — в комнате прислуги, а в столовой — осматривать? Очень возможно, что Айседора Дункан так и делает. Может быть, она в кабинете обедает, а кроликов режет в ванной. Может быть... **Но я не Айседора Дункан!!** — вдруг рявкнул он, и багровость его стала желтой. — Я буду обедать в столовой, а оперировать в операционной!*
М. А. Булгаков. Собачье сердце

*И вдруг за столиком вспорхнуло слово: **«Берлиоз!!»** Вдруг джаз развалился и затих, как будто кто-то хлопнул по нему кулаком. **«Что, что, что, что?!!» — «Берлиоз!!!»** И пошли вскакивать, пошли вскакивать...*
М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита

*— Пиши, пиши, — говорила маска, тыча пальцем ему под перо. — Теперь что же со мной, с бедным, будет? Бедная моя головушка! За что же губите вы меня, сиротинушку? Ха-ха! Ну что же? Готов протокол? Все расписавшись? Ну, теперь глядите!.. **Раз... два... три!!.***
А. П. Чехов. Маска

Мне кажется, что использование "нестандартных" знаков вполне возможно и нужно. Только употребление их должно быть дозировано (не из предложения в предложение) и оправдано контекстом: ведь главная роль таких комбинаций — привлечение внимания читателя, указание на необычность происходящего или резкую смену интонации.
Очень осторожным должно быть такое употребление, неназойливым.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!

Comment: И Вам, Артём, поклон — за поддержку моего ответа.

Comment: Да не за что) Хотелось оправдать постановку двух ВЗ, потому что их часто ставят некоторые близкие мне люди, и я вернулся к этой теме, прочитал ваш последний абзац, и мне он очень понравился. Вижу в *!!* большее чувство по отношению к собеседнику, чем в одном, и в то же время отсутствие какой-то стандартной торжественности, как при трёх, больше искренности, что ли. Хотя в некоторых случаях, конечно, ставлю и три. Например, три чаще при поздравлении с днём рождения (когда от всей души поздравляешь), а два во фразе типа "очень рад" (хотя и в ней можно три).

Comment: Иногда, считаю, можно и больше трёх ставить, но совсем редко: когда радость бьёт через край. Чаще всего это бывает от чего-то неожиданного, когда прочитал какую-то прекрасную новость и сразу же пишешь эмоционально, не боясь сделать опечатку.

Answer (score 1):

Современные правила трактуют составные знаки ("?!", "...", "!!!" и "???", "?.." и "!.." как один знак, исключение может представлять составной ", -" - который, в зависимости от синтаксической роли, может считаться либо единым, либо состоящим из двух самостоятельных.

Знака "!!" в этом списке нет. Следовательно, любое его возможное появление - главным образом в художественной литературе и личной корреспонденции - следует трактовать либо как шалость автора, либо архаизм тех времен, когда пунктуационные правила не были доведены до сегодняшнего уровня.

Есть еще несколько случаев появления знака "!!" в специального рода изданиях. В математике он означает "двойной" факториал (термин, кстати говоря, неудачный, лучше бы "половинный"), в шахматной нотации - очень сильный, блестящий ход и проч. К пунктуации в русском языке все ж это не имеет ни малейшего отношения.
Впрочем, даже в этих случаях это не два знака подряд, а именно один, особый, составной знак со своим смыслом, который не является простым удвоением одинарного.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно!